# Why does GO mod tidy not work with bitbucket

Tags: windows, git, go, bitbucket

I'm attempting to use private repositories as go libraries.

Whenever i try to run go get og god mod tidy, i get this kind of error

```
>go get bitbucket.org/myworkspace/myRepo
go get bitbucket.org/myworkspace/myRepo: reading https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myworkspace/myRepo?fields=scm: 404 Not Found
```

I've found multiple suggestions to fix this, with git config insteadOf url reqriting, but it doesn't work, and it all seems to assume that go will clone the library repo via git, and not the api.

My colleague who is running Linux, tried this and it worked, and at no point does it appear to use api.bitbucket.org instead of just bitbucket.org.

I've tried calling https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myworkspace/myRepo?fields=scm via Insomnia, with credentials, and i get the repo back just fine.

Why does go use the bitbucket api on windows, and how can i have it use credentials, so it can find the repo ?

Comment: What version of Go are you using? ([this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-articles/Changes-to-Bitbucket-API-Requires-Latest-Version-of-Go/ba-p/1975819) may be a factor). I recently rebuilt a windows machine and found that the [Git Credential Manager](https://github.blog/2022-04-07-git-credential-manager-authentication-for-everyone/) and `GOPRIVATE` was all that was needed to work with private Bitbucket repos.

Comment: @Brits updating my local go version to the newest version fixed the issue. Figured it out thanks to the link you provided. 
If you want to post it as an answer, i'll accept it. otherwise ill post the answer myself, so it's not hidden as a comment :)

Comment: Done - may I suggest that you also edit your question (the title does not really reflect the real issue) as others may be facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a [change made by Bitbucket](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-articles/Changes-to-Bitbucket-API-Requires-Latest-Version-of-Go/ba-p/1975819) (rolling out from June 1st 2022):

> Rolling out these changes will break previous versions of Go due to the fact that the go command relies on a 403 response to fetch repositories hosted on Bitbucket Cloud. This means that users who use older versions of Go with private repositories, for example CI/CD builds with Go dependencies, will run into 404 errors.

Go has been updated to support these changes; version 1.18 includes the change but if you are running an earlier version you may need to upgrade to a later minor revision (change is in `1.17.7` and `1.16.14`). The relevant Go issue [is here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/50810) (the aim of the change is something different but it resolves the issue).

> Why does go use the bitbucket api on windows...

Go was using the API to determine if the Bitbucket repo was using Git or Mercurial (Bitbucket is [dropping support for Mercurial](https://bitbucket.org/blog/sunsetting-mercurial-support-in-bitbucket)).

As mentioned in the comments I've found that the new [Git Credential Manager](https://github.blog/2022-04-07-git-credential-manager-authentication-for-everyone/) removes the need for the workarounds previously required to access private Bitbuicket repos. Using the credential manager and setting `GOPRIVATE` was all that was needed..

Answer (score 1):

You can first export the private repository with the command `export GOPRIVATE=<remote module name>`. Then you can run the command `env GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1 go get <remote module name>` so that if the credentials are not configured, you get a prompt.